# php get for POST or use value

Tags: php

I have a php function which gets a value from previous page but I want to have an existing value just in case if I leave the field empty.

Example:

```
$age = $_POST['age'];
```

want to add if statament if age is empty user 50 as a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$age = isset( $_GET['age'] ) ? (int) $_GET['age'] : 50 ;
```

Comment: That way you're not validating if the value is an integer. Use is_numeric () if you want to do this validation. As Lawrence mentioned below.

Comment: I cast $_GET['age'] to int, so it will always be an integer. Yes, your code is better practice, but I dont think it will be an issue in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Standard If Else 
if(isset($_GET['age']) && is_numeric($_GET['age'])){
    $age = $_GET['age'];
}else{
    $age = 50;
}

// Or a One-line Ternary
$age = isset($_GET['age']) && is_numeric($_GET['age']) ? $_GET['age'] : 50;
?>
```